# How does spark dataframe saveAsTable auto cast data type

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

What does dataframe saveAsTable(Append mode) do when target table has the different data type with current dataframe schema.
for example:

```
> val df = Seq((1L,1),(2L,1),(3L,1),(456789234L,1)).toDF("i","p")
> df.printSchema
root
 |-- i: long (nullable = false)
 |-- p: integer (nullable = false)
> df.write.mode("append").format("hive").partitionBy("p").saveAsTable("default.ljh_test2")
```

and the existing hive table is created by:

```
CREATE TABLE default.ljh_test2 (i int) PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS ORC;
```

it seems the dataframe could write the data to hive table, but the column `i` is `bigint` in dataframe but `int` int hive.
I want to know how does the spark dataframe do the data type cast, where can I find he relevant docs.
Thanks.

Comment: spark version 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

1. hive: https://data-flair.training/blogs/hive-data-types/
2. spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html
3. hive vs spark: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_supported_types.html

Comment: so here I expect the saveAsTable operation throws a exception, cause the data type not match in spark dataframe and hive table, but in fact, it write the df data to the hive table, I want to know how does the spark dataframe do the cast(long/bigint to int).